# Login Page on keydown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to login a page on `button` click and on "Enter" `keydown` event also, but the `keydown` portion of the code is not working. It return an error that the user is not found, which mean it's the `catch error` block that gets called. But on the `button` click portion, which is similar to the `keydown` portion code, everything works fine.

Here is the code.

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const LogIn = () => {
  const milliseconds = 3600000;
  localStorage.setItem("twoHours", JSON.stringify(milliseconds));
  const userRef = useRef();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [keyCode, setKeyCode] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    userRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
  }, []);

  async function keyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.code === "Enter") {
      try {
        const data = await Axios.post("http://localhost:3500/examAuth", {
          login: input,
        });
        setError(false);
        setErrorMessage("");
        navigate("/examSection", { state: { user: data.data } });
      } catch (error: any) {
        setError(true);
        setErrorMessage(error.response.data.message);
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await Axios.post("http://localhost:3500/examAuth", {
        login: input,
      });
      setError(false);
      navigate("/examSection", { state: { user: data.data } });
      setErrorMessage("");
    } catch (error: any) {
      setError(true);
      setErrorMessage(error.response.data.message);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="">
        <div className="w-1/6 mx-auto mt-10">
          <img src="images/editedConst.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 w-3/4 mx-auto mt-10">
          <label
            className="text-yellow-700 text-xl w-2/4 mx-auto"
            htmlFor="logIn"
          >
            Login
          </label>
          <input
            ref={userRef}
            className="input w-2/4 mx-auto"
            autoComplete="off"
            autoSave="off"
            type="text"
            value={input}
            name="login"
            placeholder="application number"
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value.trim().toUpperCase())}
            required
          />
          {error && (
            <p className="mt-1 mx-auto w-2/4 text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center w-2/4 mx-auto mt-8">
          <button
            className="btn shadow shadow-yellow-800"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
          >
            Log In
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default LogIn;
```

I cant seem to find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: When using a plain javascript eventlistener on the document in react, State variables won't update inside the event.

A better practice would be to use React events.

For example a form element with an on submit to handle both on click and on Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one answer: wrap your inputs in `<form>`. Then you can listen to it's event on submission and prevent default and / or place your logic. This approach has innumerable advantages (Password managers support and accessibility) to name two most obvious. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.